# On the invetiblity of adjacency matrix with self loop

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, inverse

$A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is an adjacency matrix. For $i=1,\dots,n$, $A(i,i)=1$. For $i,j=1,\dots,n$ and $i\neq j$, $A(i,j)=A(j,i) \in \{0,1\}$. Each row vector of $A$ is different, is $A$ invertible? The problem is from research.

Comment: did you try to manually construct? for which $n$?

Comment: you should update your question with (a) in what context you have encountered the problem (e.g. homework is ok, or some independent research) so we can get some idea of where this is generally coming from, and (b) what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. This way we can guide you properly.

Comment: @monie Clearly you've seen that second comment. So, what exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee that $A$ will be invertible. As a counterexample, consider the adjacency matrix for the path path of length 5, namely

$$
A = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1}.
$$
There are no counterexamples of size $n \times n$ for $n<5$.

---

Here's the script that I used to find a counterexample (before cleaning it up using permutation similarity)

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import det
import time

def powerset(iterable, smallest=0, largest=None):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    if largest is None:
        largest = len(s)
    else:
        largest = min(len(s),largest)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(smallest,largest+1))

for n in range(2,6):
    start = time.time()
    print(f"n = {n}:")
    idx = [(i,j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i)]
    for x in powerset(idx, smallest = n):
        row,col = zip(*x) if x else ([],[])
        A = np.ones((n,n),dtype = int)
        A[row,col] = 0
        A[col,row] = 0
        if len(set(map(tuple,A.tolist()))) == n and round(det(A),10) == 0:
            print("\tcounterexample:")
            for r in A:
                print('\t',*r)
            break
    else:
        print("\tno counterexamples")
    print(f"\t~~Execution time: {time.time()-start:.2e} seconds~~")
```

The resulting output on my device:

```
n = 2:
    no counterexamples
    ~~Execution time: 1.15e-03 seconds~~
n = 3:
    no counterexamples
    ~~Execution time: 2.81e-03 seconds~~
n = 4:
    no counterexamples
    ~~Execution time: 9.43e-04 seconds~~
n = 5:
    counterexample:
     1 0 0 0 1
     0 1 0 1 0
     0 0 1 1 1
     0 1 1 1 0
     1 0 1 0 1
    ~~Execution time: 6.42e-03 seconds~~
```

The example found in this way corresponds to the path $0\to4\to2\to3\to1$.